# DL Query Parser

Tags: owl, owl-api

In the code below, I'm trying to understand how the class expression is finally obtained but not really getting the point.

```java
ShortFormProvider shortFormProvider = new SimpleShortFormProvider();
        ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser parser = new ManchesterOWLSyntaxEditorParser(schema.getFactory(), query);
        parser.setDefaultOntology(schema.getSchema());
        Set<OWLOntology> importsClosure = schema.getSchema().getImportsClosure();
        BidirectionalShortFormProvider bidiShortFormProvider = new BidirectionalShortFormProviderAdapter(schema.getSchema().getOWLOntologyManager(),importsClosure, shortFormProvider);
        OWLEntityChecker entityChecker = new ShortFormEntityChecker(bidiShortFormProvider);
        parser.setOWLEntityChecker(entityChecker);      
        OWLClassExpression classExpression;
        classExpression = parser.parseClassExpression();
```

I'm stuck mainly on the `shortformprovider` and `bidirectionalshortform` provider. What are their function? Can someone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

The `ShortFormProvider` and `BidirectionalShortFormProvider` are objects that help you to handle the abbreviations (shotforms) of URIs. For instance `http://www.example.org/Cat` has `Cat` as shortform. The shortforms are useful to formulate OWL expressions in a compact way without using URI prefixes.

According to the documentation:

**ShortFormProvider:**
*A short form provider produces renderings of entities.  These renderings are strings which in general can be used for display and serialisation purposes.  A given entity only has one short form for a given short form provider. However, a short form may map to multiple entities for a given short form provider. In other words, for a given short form provider the mapping from entity to short form is functional, but is not inverse functional i.e. an injective mapping.*

**BidirectionalShortFormProvider:**
*A short form provider which is capable of translating back and forth between entities and their short forms.*

Comment: So, if I understand, the parses uses the BidirectionalShortFormProvider to converts each entities in the DL Query to the Full IRI based the classes in the ontology (including the IMPORT Closure)